# WPF ComboBox: SelectedValuePath and IsEditable trouble

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I've got a WPF ComboBox bound to an ObservableCollection. I set the SelectedValuePath to "Code.Value" and the DisplayMemberPath to "Name" properties. I would like to enable the ComboBox for allowing manual values that are not available through the popup. I have the following trouble:

- using SelectedValue binding does not write the manual value into the bound property, because the text search does not find a match for any item's displaymemeberpath value
- using Text binding sets the value in both cases, but when I select a value of of the popup, the displaymemberpath value is stored, not the value in the SelectedValuePath.

How can I enable the Combobox to use SelectedValuePath' value on selection AND text value when manually typing?

Thanks a lot for help!